# Produce pretty cluster plots using KMeans

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cluster-analysis

I have been meaning to produce similar plots like [image] using matplotlib on Python, where there is a shaded region depicting the cluster with all the cluster points inside the region. But, I don't see how I can achieve that, any ideas?

The plots are similar to https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.11-k-means.html; but just require a shaded region in the background.

Comment: I don't think this is "pretty", but quite ugly. It's also often misinterpreted.

Comment: I believe `beauty` is a vague concept. Until we define `beauty`, anything can be considered `pretty/ugly`. Anyway, here is an example of what I am seeking https://imgur.com/r1eQzYs - and I find it pretty. If you could tell me how one can misinterpret such plots, it would be great! Thanks xx

Comment: The colorization etc. often gives the false impression that the grouping is good or even significant. The automatic dimension reduction in clusplot causes distortion, too, hence further reducing interpretability.

Comment: I agree but sometimes in cases of outliers (say), it gets extremely hard to visualize a small yellow dot in some corner of the frame; and thus with such shaded regions, similar issues can become a little easy to deal with, even if not entirely appropriate.

Comment: Here is a current example of misinterpreting clusplot: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/393554/7828

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code (partially taken from `astroML.plotting.tools`): it takes two compulsory parameters, the mean (that is, the center of each  KMean ellipse), and the associated covariance. It produces than a set of ellipses of different scales (by default, one associated to the covariance matrix, one twice as large, and one tree times as large); it accepts arguments that are passed directly to the `matplotlib` routines.

```
from matplotlib import pyplos as plt

def draw_ellipse(mu, C, scales=[1, 2, 3], ax=None, **kwargs):
    from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    # find principal components and rotation angle of ellipse
    sigma_x2 = C[0, 0]
    sigma_y2 = C[1, 1]
    sigma_xy = C[0, 1]

    alpha = 0.5 * np.arctan2(2 * sigma_xy,
                             (sigma_x2 - sigma_y2))
    tmp1 = 0.5 * (sigma_x2 + sigma_y2)
    tmp2 = np.sqrt(0.25 * (sigma_x2 - sigma_y2) ** 2 + sigma_xy ** 2)

    sigma1 = np.sqrt(tmp1 + tmp2)
    sigma2 = np.sqrt(tmp1 - tmp2)

    for scale in scales:
        ax.add_patch(Ellipse((mu[0], mu[1]),
                             2 * scale * sigma1, 2 * scale * sigma2,
                             alpha * 180. / np.pi,
                                  **kwargs))
```

You can pass to it parameters such as the fill color `fc='blue'` or the alpha transparency: for example

```
draw_ellipse(mean, covariance_matrix, scales=[2], ax=ax,
             ec='k', fc='white', alpha=0.2)
```

Comment: Hey @MarcoLombardi, thanks for this but I am still trying to tweak it a bit according to my code; Will accept it once achieved :)

Comment: Sure, no problem, let me know if you need any help.